# SQL Server creating view need a statement after having

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL Server table with this data:

```
ID   Name   Type
-------------------
1    ZZ     INPUT
2    AA     INPUT
3    CC     OUTPUT
4    ZZ     OUTPUT
5    AA     INPUT
6    CC     INPUT
7    KK     OUTPUT
8    TT     INPUT
9    CC     OUTPUT
10   DD     OUTPUT
```

As a result, I would like the only names that are used one time. And of the ones that are used ones only the OUTPUT type.

Correct result

```
ID   Name   Type
-------------------
1    KK     OUTPUT
2    DD     OUTPUT
```

I can do it by creating two views. Use the first view as a view in between. Can I achieve the result with one view?

Comment: and what did you tried already?

Comment: A view in a view can be rewritten where the first view is merely a subquery in the FROM clause of the other view.

Comment: I would strongly urge you to avoid using nested views. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/performance-sql-server/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven You don't need multiple views this, it sounds like a pretty typical row_number query can solve this easily.

Answer (score 0):

you only need a group by query and checks for `count(*) = 1`

```
select row_number() over (order by Name) as ID, Name
from   your_table
group by Name
having count(*) = 1
and    min(Type) = 'OUTPUT';
```